# OpenCV Library error with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, android-studio

I'm having issues with current Android project I'm working on, It has OpenCV Library imported as Module and set as dependency. After updating Android Studio from 0.8.14 to 1.0, and trying to sync Gradle I'm getting following error:

> Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set
>   to 'org.opencv' in default config.

I'd like to post my project structure and grade file, but I can't upload images yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try commenting `applicationID` out of your library module's `build.gradle` file. Like this:

```
defaultConfig {
//    applicationId "com.library.package"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

I'm still new at Android Studio, and am by no means an expert, but I got the same error after upgrading and this seems to fix it.

Comment: just adding a link to the official documentation regarding applicationId and packagename: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use comment, but instead to fix it, it generate new error (SOLVED).

With "applicationId 'lecho.lib.hellocharts'" enabled:

> Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'lecho.lib.hellocharts' in default config

With "applicationId 'lecho.lib.hellocharts'" disabled (as comment):

> A problem occurred configuring project ':hellocharts-library'.
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin$Rules#addConfiguredPublicationsToProjectPublicationRegistry(org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectPublicationRegistry, org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension, org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectIdentifier)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

**[I found solution.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81813&thanks=81813&ts=1417772419)**

Comment: Build script for hellocharts library has been [updated](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/commit/be9fd842f9194784edae0a0564ca3257f78dd214), error with maven-publish plugin was caused by the attempt to use applicationId element as library artifactId.